# is there a way to dump all postgres database from localhost to remote server without restoration in ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, cron, pg-dump

I want to dump all my PostgreSQL databases directly to a remote server from my localhost, just a simple .sql file and create a cronjob for it. Is this possible ?

Comment: Just to be clear. You want to dump them as files, but on a remote server

Comment: Yes it is possible.  What did you try and what problems are you having?

Comment: Do you want to push the data from the local machine to the remote or pull it from the local on the remote? Do you have Postgres installed on both locations? If so are they the same version? Add answers as update to question.